# SPARQL query to get the information of a specific uri

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to get the id (or maybe other information) of a page with a specific uri (http://dbpedia.org/page/Weight_gain). I tried these: (none of them works)

```
select ?id WHERE {<http://dbpedia.org/page/Weight_gain>
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageID> ?id}

select ?uri ?id WHERE {?uri <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageID> ?id.
FILTER (?uri = <http://dbpedia.org/page/Weight_gain>) }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How about the opposite? Use the ID in order to get the url

Comment: @HaniGoc if you have a followup question, please ask it as a new question. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information on how to ask good questions here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual resource identifier in DBPedia is `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Weight_gain`. The URL you are using (with `/page/` instead of `/resource/`) is just the URL of the HTML representation. It's not the URI you should be using in querying via SPARQL.

This should do the trick:

```
 SELECT ?uri ?id 
 WHERE {
     ?uri <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageID> ?id.
     FILTER (?uri = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Weight_gain>) 
 }
```

[Query Result](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%3Furi%20%3Fid%20%0D%0A%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Furi%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FwikiPageID%3E%20%3Fid.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Furi%20%3D%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FWeight_gain%3E%29%20%0D%0A%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Note that that's not the *best* way to write that query, though.  It would be better to do `select ?uri ?id { values ?uri { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Weight_gain> } ?uri <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageID> ?id }`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I don't agree that that is "the best way", it depends on the SPARQL engine and how well it plans/optimizes its queries.  I left the FILTER in deliberately to stay closest to the OPs original question - a full discussion on query optimization seemed somewhat out of scope to me.

Comment: Yes, speaking in absolutes was probably inappropriate.  My point was that conceptually the query with `filter` retrieves all triples on `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageID>` (of which there are 13494818 in DBpedia) and then examines each one to filter out anything except `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Weight_gain>`.  On the other hand, the query with `values` says "let ?uri be `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Weight_gain>` and retrieve ?id such that `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Weight_gain> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageID> ?id`" (for which there's only one value on DBpedia).

Comment: I know that you know that, but I'm including the discussion for the sake of others who might not understand the intent of our earlier comments.  I know that in this case, most optimizers would do the same thing, but that's not so obvious if you start doing `filter( ?uri = ... || ?uri = ...)` or `filter( ?uri in ( ... ) )`.  I'd generally claim that being more explicit about the fact that a constant value is being provided, both for human readers and the endpoint is a clearer practice, and will play more nicely with less sophisticated endpoints.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't mean my comment as a "none of your business"-type thing :) . I would expect there to be an existing question on SO where this topic is explored in one of the answers, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: How can you use the ID now to retrieve the url of a wiki page?